# Variable switches definitions in Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a bot with a warning system with Discord.js and for some reason my variable `member` switches definitions (im not sure if I put that correctly).

```
  if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "warn"))
  {
    if(msg.member.roles.some(role => role.name === "President" || "King Prawn" || "Vice President" || "Emperor" || "IIC Director" || "SSPD Commissioner" || "Deputy IIC Director" || "IIC Agent" || "SSPD Officer" || "IRL"))
    {
      msg.channel.send(member + " has been warned.");
      logschnl.send(member + " has been warned by " + msga);
      msg.member.send("You have been warned on [server_name_here] for: " + args[1]);
    }
    else
    {
      msg.channel.send("Sorry, you don't have the needed roles to do this.");
    }
```

where:
`member = msg.mentions.user.first();`
`logschnl = client.channels.get('658917488544972811');`

Problem:
The 'definition' of `member` switches between this line: `logschnl.send(member + " has been warned by " + msga);` and this line: `msg.member.send("You have been warned on [server_name_here] for: " + args[1]);`

The output of `logschnl.send(member...)` should be and is "[Targeted User] has been warned by [person who warned them]."  However for the line `msg.member.send(...);` should send a DM to the targeted user (because they're one who was mentioned first), but it sends the DM to the person who warned them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need use `msg` when you send msg to DM member.

**msg.member** - member who send warn command

**member** - preassigned by your variable member (fist mention user in msg content)

And use role names its not best practice for validate user roles, use role.id. Better not use member as variable of mention user fist, const it as waringUser or somethink else

```
  {
    if(msg.member.roles.some(role => role.name === "President" || "King Prawn" || "Vice President" || "Emperor" || "IIC Director" || "SSPD Commissioner" || "Deputy IIC Director" || "IIC Agent" || "SSPD Officer" || "IRL"))
    {
      msg.channel.send(member + " has been warned.");
      logschnl.send(member + " has been warned by " + msga);
      member.send("You have been warned on [server_name_here] for: " + args[1])
      .catch(console.error)
    }
    else
    {
      msg.channel.send("Sorry, you don't have the needed roles to do this.");
    }
```